# Extended Events missing documentation

Tags: sql-server, performance, extended-events

I have been looking pretty hard for the documentation regarding the RingBufferTarget

```
<RingBufferTarget truncated="0" eventsPerSec="1370714" processingTime="7" totalEventsProcessed="9595" eventCount="600" droppedCount="0" memoryUsed="523832">
```

Do you know what the following attributes mean or have you found the documentation?

- truncated
- eventsPerSec
- processingTime
- totalEventsProcessed
- eventCount
- droppedCount
- memoryUsed

Comment: Does this page help you?  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/extended-events-ring_buffer/ - "Understanding the Target Data Format" section.

Comment: I found that page but thanks. It goes into a bit of detail but its still unclear what the attributes say. Its strange that there is no official documentation from MS